# Scala TypeTag doesn't prevent from Type Erasure

Tags: scala, type-erasure

In this thread, I'm writing a simple helper function for TraversableLike:

[How to specify a type parameter in calling a function while let the compiler infer the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338565/how-to-specify-a-type-parameter-in-calling-a-function-while-let-the-compiler-inf)

I implement the following function:

```
  implicit class TraversableLikeView[A, Repr](self: TraversableLike[A, Repr]) {

    def filterByType[B: TypeTag] = new FilterByType[B]

    class FilterByType[B: TypeTag] {

      def get[That](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
        val result = self.flatMap{
          v =>
            val unboxed = Utils.javaUnbox(v)
            unboxed match {
              case x: B => Some(x)
              case _ => None
            }
        }(bf)
        result
      }
    }
  }
```

The TypeTag is used since ClassTag.unapply had some problem in handling primitive classes. However, when I compile the above code I got the following warning:

```
Warning:(304, 23) abstract type pattern B is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              case x: B => Some(x)
                      ^
```

Which is against what TypeTag claim to do (ClassTag was doing an almost perfect job here). Is there a reason why TypeTag fail in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This is only supported by `ClassTag`, because you can get a `Class` from it and you can't *in general* get a `Class` from a `TypeTag`: e.g. in macros the class isn't compiled yet. But presumably you are using `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag`, in which case you can write

```
implicit val classTagB = ClassTag[B](mirror.runtimeClass(typeTag[B].tpe))
```

Comment: I thought ClassTag is already deprecated in latest Scala version and TypeTag is the successor? So what is TypeTag good for?

Comment: No, `ClassTag` isn't deprecated. `ClassManifest` is and `ClassTag` is its replacement.